Need help understanding variadic 'using' declarations
I am reading the book "C++17 - The Complete Guide", by Nicolai M. Josuttis.
Chapter 14 is entitled "Using variadic using declarations". I don't understand the sample code in it:
// Part 1: "inherit" all function call operators of passed based types:
template<typename... Ts>
struct overload : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;
}

// Part 2: base types are deduced from passed arguments
// >>>> What is it ?? -> see answer from Ted Lyngmo
// EDIT: That's also based on the fact that overload can use
//       aggregate initialization, and so that overload can be
//       instancied with a constructor with any number and types
//       (but we have to help it to deduce the types).
template<typename... Ts>
overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

// Part 3
auto twice = overload {
                [](std::string& s) { s += s; }
                [](auto& v) { v *= 2; }
             };

The code has 3 parts:

part 1: I understand we declare a class which will have finally 3 function call operators.

part 2: I don't understand this one... - what are we declaring here? Could you explain the syntax, especially overload(Ts...)?

part 3: We use aggregate initialization to initialize base classes function call operators.


If I have to read a previous chapter again, let me know which one!

Part 2 is CTAD - Class template argument deduction.

Well, you gotta expect a few nightmares from Josuttis.


template<typename... Ts>
overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;

what are we declaring here ?

This is a user-defined deduction guide. It will be used when the class template overload is instantiated without explicitly specifying any template parameters. It then helps to deduce the class to be overload<Ts...>.
In this context:
auto twice = overload {
                [](std::string& s) { s += s; },
                [](auto& v) { v *= 2; }
             };

... it makes twice of type
overload<decltype(lambda1), decltype(lambda2)>

In C++20, the implicitly generated deduction guides would be enough but in C++17 this deduction guide is needed for this type of instantiation.

Well done. It's obvious somebody spent a good deal of time steeped in C++17 lore.

@DavidC.Rankin :-) Thank you!

If I read the link you provide, the class container does declare a templatized constructor. So the guide refers to this constructor. In the code I "pasted", there is no declared constructor. And I don't see why there would a constructor generated with a list of arguments, whose each matches to one of the base class.

OK, I finally got it Thanks @TedLyngmo ! But a last dark point had to be lightened. I added some explanation in the original post.
